# URL in the angular html page not rendering correct page

Tags: html, angular

I have a URL displayed in the UI,Something like below

```
 <div class="form-group col-md-3 col-sm-3 col-xs-12">
    <label for="url" l10nTranslate
      >URL</label
    >
    <a [href]="fg.Url.value">{{
      fg.Url.value
    }}</a>
  </div>
```

So I have a clickable URL displayed in the UI below the URL label.

When I have the value of 'www.google.com/' in the URL.When I click on that it has to open the google page, instead it is routing to 'http://localhost:4202/www.google.com/' instead of going to the google page.

Please help in the regards.

Thanks

Answer (score 0, accepted):

You need to use the entire Uniform Resource Locator (URL) like so.

`https://www.google.com` instead of `www.google.com`

Otherwise html will assume a relative path, which is what you're seeing. It assumes that `www.google.com/` is some sub-page in your website.

```
  <div class="form-group col-md-3 col-sm-3 col-xs-12">
    <label for="url" l10nTranslate>URL</label>
    <a [href]="'https://' + fg.Url.value">https://{{fg.Url.value}}</a> 
    <!-- make sure fg.Url.value has http:// or https:// included at the beginning -->
  </div>
```

Answer (score 0):

Absolute routes must start with `https://` or `http://`.

You can also abreviate this by starting with `//`. 

So, your variable should start with `//` or make it in the binding itself

```
<a [href]="`//${fg.Url.value}`">{{
   fg.Url.value
}}</a>
```

Comment: Absolute routes don’t have to start with https or http they can start with any acceptable protocol.